# How does an API callback work and how can I implement one?

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I am a bit confused as to how these callbacks work.

I have seen some REST APIs ask for callback URLs mainly for authentication(Oauth) and if I understand correctly, the API calls an endpoint implemented at our backend once they're done. But if this is a website and the API calls a backend how will it call the particular session that an user triggered that API call from?

Do we generate some unique ID and use that to identify each session?

Also is it possible to implement something like this for uses other than authentication?

Excuse me if this seems trivial but I've been trying to figure it out for hours now.

Thanks in advance! :)

P.S: I'm trying it out in python using FastAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you usually include a key that identifies the "transaction". Either one that is pre-shared (for webhooks where an API makes callbacks at specific times when an event happens and the request isn't a response to something initiated by you), or one that you generate to identify the session itself after redirecting a user outside of your own application.

```
remote server makes a request to /webhooks?key=foo
```

.. or what usually happens, includes a signature as an HTTP header that signs the message based on an already exchanged key.

See for example [Stripe's webhook documentation for an example of how the request is signed](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures).

However, in the case where the user is redirected back to your application (which is the flow for many authentication schemes), the redirect back is given to the user's client - and their session will still be active. In that case the redirect will include a session identifier from the authentication system, which you can then use in your backend to verify that the user actually was authenticated and with what autorization.

```
/foo -> redirect -> https://remote/auth
(enters authentication information)
https://remote/auth -> redirect -> /authenticated?secret_key=foobar
```

Comment: So if I am to implement a webhook in my API to call the website backend, I would still need to add a transaction key, right?

Comment: A webhook is called from the third party; it's not called by yourself. If the callback is related to an operation you've performed with the third party, you'll usually get a transaction id / event id / user configured unique id back to identify the originating request, yes (such as a payment transaction).

Comment: Hey, since you said this uses transactional IDs and such, I had dropped the plan to use API callbacks. But now I am in a situation where I need to create an EC2 instance after a stripe webhook call on my API and then notify the web backend that the instance has been provisioned. Can you tell me what the best way is to go about this? I am asking it here since it seems similar to callbacks.

Comment: The webhook should call out to a worker (something like Celery would be well-suited) that would do the actual task. You could then call a webhook when the task has finished to the web backend when the task has finished, or it could add another celery task that performs whatever is required when the task has completed (such as sending out emails, updating state in a db, etc.).

Comment: Oh. But if I do that can I notify a person who's currently logged in on a browser? I mean, if I select a product, pay for it using stripe and then stripe calls my API's webhooks endpoint which provisions the instance and then notify the logged in user on the page itself that it's been provisioned instead of sending an email? I haven't done this before and it seems a bit confusing to me, so please tell me if this thought is correct. I did take a look at celery, and I kinda understand how to send an email or something, but not notify in the current session itself.

Comment: That's a different problem - in that case you'd probably use websockets or server sent events and have your app post a "message" to the bus that the websocket is listening on. The callback/webhooks structure would post that message, but otherwise is intended for communcation between server applications, not to the user's web client.

Comment: Oh, Ok. So simply websockets would work in this case? I'll try that out. Thank you!